# Schedule clockwork to run only on a specific date of the year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

I been trying schedule a job with `clockwork` to run only on day eg. February 14. But I'm not sure if is this possible because the [documentation formats](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork#valid-formats) do not have this possibility.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
Clockwork.every(1.day, 'valentines_day_job', if: lambda { |t| t.day == 14 && t.month == 2 })
```

But I would like to avoid unnecessary verification every day.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can delete the job event after run the job possibly.

Answer (score 0):

to make this work, change 1.day to 1.year